# Scroll viewport height until end continously

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I have this code to scroll the viewport height section-by-section when clicked on a fixed button until the end is reached. Then I want to fadeOut the button.

The HTML

```
<a class="cd-go">
        <img class="scroll-swipe" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/scroll_down_arrow.svg">
</a><!-- scroll btn -->
```

The js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.cd-go', function(event){                        
    event.preventDefault();
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: viewportHeight,
        complete: function () {
           $('.cd-go').fadeOut(300);
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

The problem is it is only scrollin from first to second section. How could this be section by section until the bottom?

EDIT:
Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cyt57dsj/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of the current section, and multiply `viewportHeight` by the current section. That way you can scroll section by section.

```js
var currentSection = 0;
var totalSections = document.querySelectorAll("section").length;
$(document).on('click', '.cd-go', function(event){                        
    event.preventDefault();
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    currentSection++;
    if (currentSection > totalSections - 1) currentSection = totalSections - 1;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: viewportHeight * currentSection,
        complete: function () {
           $('.cd-swipe').slideDown(300);
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
.cd-go {
   width: 209px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.17);
    height: 212px;
    border-radius: 212px;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -106px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.w-sec {
  height:100vh;
}
.w-sec:first-of-type {
  background:#fff;
}
.w-sec:nth-of-type(2) {
  background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="cd-go">
   DOWN
</a><!-- scroll btn -->

<section id="section1" class="w-sec cd-section">
 content
</section><!-- section 2 -->

<section id="section2" class="w-sec cd-section">
 content
</section><!-- section 2 -->

<section id="section3" class="w-sec cd-section">
 content
</section><!-- section 2 -->
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you be able to advise a snippet for resetting the sections when user scrolls back up?

Answer (score 1):

simply place  `$(document).height()` instead of `$(window).height()` :)

Comment: This seems to be scrolling straight to the bottom instead section-by-section to the bottom.

Comment: Owww I thought you just want to reach the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).on('click', '.cd-go', function(event){                        
event.preventDefault();
var viewportHeight = $(document).height();
$("html, body").animate({
     scrollTop: viewportHeight,
  }, {
    duration: 500,
    complete: function () {
       $('.cd-swipe').slideDown(300);
    }
  });
});
```

you are scrolling window instead of document

Comment: This seems to be scrolling straight to the bottom instead section-by-section to the bottom.